# WPF Hyperlink control in static resource not firing events

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, event-handling, resourcedictionary

I am populating a FlowDocumentScrollViewer with a FlowDocument out of a ResourceDictionary e.g.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<FlowDocument x:Key="CoursesAndModulesTooltip">
    <Paragraph>Definition</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>The course this learner is attending.</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>Reason required</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>A learner must be on a course taking one or more aims.</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">
        <Run>Link</Run>
    </Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

If I embed the code above directly into my window, then the hyperlink click is handled. If I  use the resource dictionary above, then it is not.

This is my global handler

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
        typeof(System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink),
        System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.RequestNavigateEvent,
        new System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventHandler(
            (sender, en) =>
            {
                Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(en.Uri.AbsoluteUri)
                {
                    UseShellExecute = true
                });
            }
        )
    );

    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

and this is how I am using the resource dictionary in my main window

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Document="{StaticResource CoursesAndModulesTooltip}" />
```

Is there something I need to do to have the Hyperlink in the resource dictionary to get it to fire events?

Comment: It should work for sure. Provide a minimum vialble example please.

Comment: I'm putting it down to a bug in WPF. If I hit hot reload in Visual Studio it will start working. I've abandoned this approach for now.

Comment: You can attach an intance handler to the FlowDocumentScrollViewer.